# Save a Single row of an entity in coredata instead of whole entity or context

Tags: ios

I am developing an app where I need to download some Images from server and then save them in core Data. For that I want when each single image will come it must save in core data database. So when an image complete download it just generates a notification where I want to save the only row containing this image in core data but not full entity or context.
Plz if someone can help I will be thankfull to him.

Comment: Why don't you make an Entity "Image" with only one property of type NSString. This string will be the path to the image (This means you have to save the image on disk). This is what Apple suggests when saving large files/BLOBs

Comment: thankx Marc I will try to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

You couldn't save a property of some entity. In general you don't care about what to save and how it is saved, because you save context changes.